# gridview SelectedIndexChanged Event is not firing.I am using asp.net 4.0 .By the way rowdatabound event is firing perfectly

Tags: asp.net

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridPlace" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="800px"
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
        CellPadding="5" OnRowDataBound="gridPlace_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridPlace_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DetailID" DataField="PID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" ControlStyle-Width="200px" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.png" ToolTip="Click To Edit this Record" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="40px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <h2 class="CustomErrorMsg">
            No Record Found</h3>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my html markup for the gridview.RowDatabound event is firing perfectly.Kindly Help

Comment: You need a select column

Comment: What you mean by select column ?

Comment: `<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" />`

Comment: oh...Thank you so much.It worked just one more thing.Can I show image (like Edit or delete image) in CommandField?

Comment: You can use the buttonType property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just click anywhere on a row to fire the event, you will need JavaScript to do that. Think these would help

1. `<asp:GridView Runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" />` - [How to: Enable Default Selection in the GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbk82279%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
2. Add

   `<asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Select" />
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>`
3. Use JavaScript if you don't want the select button to appear - http://forums.asp.net/t/992062.aspx/1
4. `<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Image" />` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx

Comment: Thats why I have added asp:image button in template column .just tell my when clicking that Image button which event is fired?

Comment: For Edit, add `CommandName="Edit"` to the button, for Delete, I think `CommandName="Delete"`

Comment: Thank you so much.Appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had these symptoms using TemplateFields.

TemplateFields allow you to have items in different columns with the same ID - without intellisense highlighting an error.

Under those circumstances, two links with the same ID can prevent the click being resolved.

Ususally this will be a copy and paste error.

Hope this helps someone!